# I am trying to put multiple items using BatchWriteItem function of DynamoDB, but I am getting ResourceNotFoundException error

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

As I wrote it at the title, I am trying to put the multiple items using BatchWriteItem function of DynamoDB on AWS Lambda function, but I am getting an ResourceNotFoundException.
I researched about why this error maybe happen and checked the followings

- If the region is correct
- If the table is existed
- If the permissions with dynamodb:BatchWriteItem are assigned to the user or role

I confirmed that the above things are set up correctly, but I have been getting the error yet.

Answer (score 0):

The reasons you stated are the reasons you would receive a `ResourceNotFoundException`.

As for BatchWriteItem, because you state the tableName for each part of the batch, it can be quite easy to get the table name wrong.

What I suggest:

1. Make sure the credentials you are using are correct, try out a simple PutItem on the table
2. Make sure the table name in the batch of items is in the correct location.
3. Make sure the region is correct

If that fails, edit your question to add the code which you are trying.